# Office 365 API Search replace on Word online (fault?)

Tags: javascript, office365api, office-js

I have developed an add-in using the Office api (JavaScript)

It works fine on ***Word desktop client (2016)*** but using **Word 365 online** version the "search and replace" code I use nudges the replaced string sometimes left, sometimes right, sometimes exact.
This is quite possibly a fault in Word online, but to be sure I am asking here to see if any of you know why this is occurring.

It seems to be caused by Word using a count of characters between replacements, then replacing regardless.

Here is a short example, the searched string is (greater than and less than replaced using £ as I can't post the symbols in a meaningful manner!)

```
£client name£!
```

and in this case I replace using "**Super Client**", you can see the replace misses. (this is just a piece of the text, in some places it hits fine)

We understand **£cSuper Client** immediate and long-term objectives for this project and we have structured this our plan to respond to your initial requirements, in partnership with **£cliSuper Client**r over the coming years.

The code I run to replace (in the api) is:

```
Word.run(function (ctx) {
 var results = ctx.document.body.search("£client name£!");
 ctx.load(results);
 return ctx.sync()
 .then(function () {
  var replaceCount = results.items.length;
  if (!replaceCount || replaceCount === 0) {
      return;
  }
for (var i = 0; i < replaceCount; i++) {     
results.items[i].insertText(userClientName, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

results.items[i].font.color = "#005882";

}      return ctx.sync()
  .then (function () {// do something }
```

Comment: btw independent of recognizing this as a bug (check my answer) uii wonder about your scenario. i am assuming you rather use content controls to replace the customers in a template, right?

Comment: Sorry for slow response - I have had a busy few days! I tried the content controls variant, but prefer the simple string replacement approach. Content controls seem a little overkill in our use scenario. We can have up to 1280 (currently) client name replacements, so content controls are a little too much. We also have some concerns that our standards team run scripts to clean hidden data, which could results in issues! I am still researching the use cases for content controls, so it is possible I'll return to them for some usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this Jerry, this is effectively a bug (known issue) and its in the process to be fixed. Will update this question when the fix is live. THanks!